# search for a value in dynamic object list in c#

Tags: c#, list, search, dynamic, filter

Here is my code to search a value in field 'name',
Now I want all the items in the list which contains value at any field (may be at id or name)

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var p = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;
        ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando)["Id"] = (i % 2)*10;
        ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando)["name"] = (i).ToString();
        list.Add(expando);
    }

    var value = list.FindAll(x =>
    {
        var dic = x as IDictionary<string, object>;
        return 
            dic["name"].ToString().Contains("value");
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciable .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Keys` collection

```
return dic.Keys.Any(key => dic[key].ToString().Contains("value"));
```